# END command in GW-BASIC

Tags: gw-basic

I am using the `AUTO` command in GW-BASIC 3.23. After I type a program I want to run it. The `END` command won't return me to command level. I also tried CTRL-BREAK and <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>.

Comment: This is *not* a duplicate of the linked question. The linked question asks how to exit the BASIC environment, while this question asks how to exit `AUTO` mode, which is an interpreter mode that generates line numbers automatically, and return to normal operation. Note that following the answer to the linked question will exit the interpreter altogether and discard the program in memory, which is  not what the OP wants.

Answer (score 2):

Are you perhaps running GW-BASIC in DOSBox? If so, try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> -<kbd>Scroll Lock</kbd> , as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Break</kbd> does not work correctly in DOSBox. That said, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> should also get you out of `AUTO` mode, so I don't know why that didn't work for you.

Typing the `END` statement will not get you out of `AUTO` mode, it will just store a program line with `END` in it.

Answer (score 1):

After writing the `END` command press **ENTER** and on the next line now press ***ctrl-Break***. I hope you will now get out of the programming mode and switch to the command or direct mode.